# Code to be run once and only once at each rails server restart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading

My application is 2 fold. First it runs a thread that reads an Arduino output to get the data and store them in my model. It does that forever as the Arduino is sensing data forever. Second the main web application analyses the data and draws fancy graphs.

When I start the rails server, I would like the reading thread to run once and only once.

My current implementation is with a thread in the main controller of my application (as I need the model to store the data). Each time I refresh the page, a new thread is created. This is not what I want as concurrent access to the Arduino creates false readings.

I guess it is a pretty classic problem but I do not see what is the way of getting that behaviour with Rails. I have been looking and googling for a week now but I am still stuck.

Thanks in advance.
Pierre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed with @rovermicrover, you should consider separating the task of interacting with the arduino from the web app.

To that end, I'd recommend that you create a rake task for that piece.  Then you might consider managing the start/stop/restart of that rake task via [foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman).  It's a nice clean way to go and you can also do capistrano integration pretty easily.

Comment: Thanks for your help, deeply appreciated. I guess the task will be able to use the same Active Record as the application ? is that it ? Thanks again.

Comment: Yup, if the task specifies `:environment` as a dependency, your app will be loaded and you can do normal stuff like use your AR models.  PS: +1's are the way to say thanks around here.  ;)

Comment: Sorry I did not know. I ticked the question in green, does that makes a +1 ?

Comment: The green tick means you've accepted the answer.  Do that if the answer solved your problem.  If an answer is helpful, click the up arrow just above that.  :)  Also welcome to SO.

Comment: I cannot vote yet as my reputation is to low. Still, it really solved my problem and my application is running perfectly now, I even published it on gitHub (I was so happy) ;-)) Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong Tool For the Job. Kind of. Your not going to want the rails app to monitor the Arduino output, rails isn't really ment for something like that. Your best having a separate dedicated app read the Arduino output, and then save the information to a database.

Arduino Output ---> Application Parsing Output ---> DB ---> Rails App

This way your web application can focus on web, and not be torn between jobs.

An interesting way to do this would be to have the parsing application be a ruby app, and use Active Record outside of rails in this instance. While I have never done it, people have used Active Record in simliar setups in pure Ruby apps. Here is an old example.

http://blog.aizatto.com/2007/05/21/activerecord-without-rails/

This way also when you redeploy your rails app, data will still be able to be collected. It also creates a firewall so if your rails app explodes, or goes down the data collection will be unaffected.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I was thinking about it but I thought I had the rail server running to use the ActiveRecords. I will look into your example. Again thanks a lot.